How can i close the mud blazor dialog?
I am simply trying to close this dialog,specifically when i click on the cancel button. i have read the documentation and i dont think i understand how it works any help is greatly appreciated. I have tried looking at the Mud docs , stack posts youtube videos and i cant seem to figure out what the issue is. the close functionality is applied to the close cancel button but nothing is happening.
dialog component
@using MudBlazor

<MudDialog>
    <TitleContent>
        Dialog Title
    </TitleContent>
    <DialogContent>
        Dialog Content
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton style="background-color: red" OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton style="background-color: green;" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private MudDialogInstance? MudDialog { get; set; }

    private void Submit() => MudDialog?.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));

    private void Cancel() => MudDialog?.Cancel();
} 

parent component
@using BlazorContactsApp.Services
@using BlazorContactsApp.Components
@using MudBlazor
@inject ContactService ContactService
@inject IDialogService DialogService

@page "/"
<div style="margin: 20px">
    <MudButton OnClick="OpenDialogAsync" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary">
    Open Simple Dialog
</MudButton>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new app.</p>
</div>

 @if (contacts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    
        @foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            <MudCard Color="grey" style="border: 1px solid grey; margin: 2rem; width: 20vw; border-radius: 5px">
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">Name : @contact.Name</MudText>
                </MudCardContent>
                <MudDivider />
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">Number : @contact.Number</MudText>
                </MudCardContent>
            </MudCard>
        }

} 

@code {
    private List<ContactsApi.Models.Contact> contacts = new List<ContactsApi.Models.Contact>();

         protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        contacts = await ContactService.GetContactsAsync();
    }

   private async Task OpenDialogAsync()
    {
        var options = new DialogOptions { CloseOnEscapeKey = true, CloseButton = true  };
        var parameters = new DialogParameters();

        var dialog = DialogService.Show<AddContactDialog>("Dialog Title", parameters, options);
        var result = await dialog.Result;

     
    } 

   
} 


Deployed a Mud Blazor 8 solution Server with Global Interactivity.
I've built the following MRE from your question code.
AddContactDialog.razor

<MudDialog>
    <TitleContent>
        Dialog Title
    </TitleContent>
    <DialogContent>
        Dialog Content
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton style="background-color: red" OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton style="background-color: green;" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private MudDialogInstance? MudDialog { get; set; }

    private void Submit() => MudDialog?.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));

    private void Cancel() => MudDialog?.Cancel();
} 

Home:
@page "/"
@inject IDialogService DialogService

<div style="margin: 20px">
    <MudButton OnClick="OpenDialogAsync" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary">
        Open Simple Dialog
    </MudButton>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new app.</p>
</div>

@code {
    private async Task OpenDialogAsync()
    {
        var options = new DialogOptions { CloseOnEscapeKey = true, CloseButton = true };
        var parameters = new DialogParameters();

        var dialog = DialogService.Show<AddContactDialog>("Dialog Title", parameters, options);
        var result = await dialog.Result;
    }
}

Opens and closes as expected.  Try it.
The only conclusions I can come to is:

Missing critical information or
the code you're showing isn't what your running.

